# Sort dictionary consists of lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have formed a dictionary, this dictionary consists of lists. I would like to sort the lists according to the score value.

ex.

```
dict1 = {
'Name': ['Romy', 'Jenny', 'Jack', 'Mark'],
'Score' : [6.5, -1.2, 3.3, 1], 
'ID': ['Ka11', 'Ka12', 'Ka13', 'Ka14'],
}
```

I need the final result to be sorted as follows

```
dict1 = {
'Name': ['Jenny', 'Mark', 'Jack', 'Romy'],
'Score' : [-1.2, 1 , 3.3, 6.5], 
'ID': ['Ka12', 'Ka14', 'Ka13', 'Ka11'],
}
```

I used the following command, but gives me error

`sorted_dict = sorted(dict1, key=lambda e: sorted(dict1['Score'][e]))`

how can I reflect sorting one list in the dictionary to affect the other lists?

Comment: You are kinda asking for trouble using a dictionary this way.  It can be done, but when you add something new, you'll need to re-sort everything, etc.  Several other probs.  There is likely a better way to organize your data structure.  Whey you use this data structure, how do you access it?  Do you look up student name or ID to get info?  Or are you just looking for a container to hold all of the records and then (when needed) sort it by score?

Comment: Do you really need a dictionary here? I know what you are looking for can be done but i am curious about the use case.

Comment: Thanks for helping. try to make my database as list of same objects. Like list of names, ids, and score. So I can work easily on each list separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other version:

```
s = dict1['Score'][:]
for v in dict1.values():
    v[:] = [i for _, i in sorted(zip(s, v))]

print(dict1)
```

Prints:

```
{'Name': ['Jenny', 'Mark', 'Jack', 'Romy'], 'Score': [-1.2, 1, 3.3, 6.5], 'ID': ['Ka12', 'Ka14', 'Ka13', 'Ka11']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
keys = ['Score','Name','ID']
s = sorted(zip(*[dict1[x] for x in keys]))

for i,l in enumerate(keys):
    dict1[l] = [x[i] for x in s]
```